# How to connect to QBO API (oauth) via a Vagrant box?

Tags: laravel, oauth, vagrant, quickbooks-online

I am trying to connect to the Quickbooks Online API via oauth from a Vagrant box (Laravel Homestead), however, after clicking on "connect me", a new window is opened, redirects to myhost.com/oauth.php and returns a blank white page.  Typically, this second window should close and redirect back to myhost.com with a  "You have connected to Quickbooks!" message.

This works fine on my server. I am trying to figure out what is different in configuration, but no success.

my `/etc/hosts` file shows:

```
192.168.10.10   www.rugapp.com

192.168.10.10  homestead  # VAGRANT: fea709db2e32a39618e4b4c9f1fe1026 (default) / 88840d50-7152-4760-9be1-5f68ce5fde1d
```

As shown above, I have installed the vagrant plugin hostsupdater and ran the two commands:

`config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.10"`

`config.vm.hostname = "www.rugap.com"`

Is it possible to connect to Quickbooks Online via a Vagrant box?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the authentication requires a publicly accessible URL, and the hostname seems to be mapped to a local IP (which the authentication service cannot reach). You could try using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel your app to be publicly accessible and see if it works then (you'll get a URL like http://mysubdomain.ngrok.com which is public).

---

I haven't tried running **ngrok** from a Vagrant box but the following might work:

1. SSH into your vagrant machine
2. Download (wget) ngrok using the link on their website and unzip it, or [install it through npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ngrok)
3. Run `ngrok 80` (which would forward traffic from port 80, you can use any port you need). This will start the tunneling and give the forwarding URL.

Comment: I did configure ngrok to tunnel my app.  However, the exact problem remains.  It must be something else.  Thank you.

Comment: ngrok tunnels traffic for a given port, it doesn't replace your webserver altogether, it just _forwards_ it's response so it can be served publicly. I've updated my answer with some instructions.

Comment: For vagrant, given my IP shown in the question, I had to run `ngrok 192.168.10.10:80` and it worked great.  My app was tunneled to a public address. However, the original problem remains.  There must be some other difference between my server and the local configurations.

Comment: If I'm reading their [oAuth Documentation](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0060_authentication_and_authorization/oauth_management_api) correctly they mention a parameter **grantUrl** and part of the description reads _"Make sure this matches the value of the **Host Name Domain** field in your app's setting page on its **Development** tab"_. Is it possible that the authentication works only if the request comes from the configured domain? (that would explain why it works from your server and not from another hostname).

Comment: That is only relevant if your app is in production.  I've left the defaults in (Domain.Here) and it still works with my server.  I really appreciate you looking into this.  For now, I'll just stick to developing exclusively on my server. Thanks again.

Comment: My hunch right now is that ngrock is forwarding the HTTP port but MySQL is not being forwarded. I'm looking into how to forward both ports now.

Comment: That doesn't matter, because the MySQL server is being accessed by the Laravel app and they're both on the same machine (their context is `localhost` so it doesn't get affected by the forwarding, as far as the app is concerned it can access the db server on `localhost:3306`). Keep in mind, the app execution is still being done by your homestead virtual machine, the only thing **ngrok** does is forward the response through their own server, so that it's mapped to the public subdomain. I'm guessing you don't have a dedicated machine only for the MySQL server.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.   If I find a way to get this working, I'll post the solution to my specific problem.  Thanks and have a great day.